# Flume Java Custom Sink and Source

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-kafka, flume, flume-ng

Flume Version :- 1.6

Kafka Version :- 1.0.0

Zookeeper Version :- 3.4.10

We had a quick requirement to connect Flume with Kafka and Hadoop, so we ingested from Kafka Consumer and ingested the events to Hadoop. Everything was configured using the conf file, till here everything was fine.

Now we need to check whether it can be done using custom Java code. I have tried a lot of options available in the internet to design a kafka source and HDFS sink. I tried this in the cloudera VM.

Kafka and zookeeper is both up and running.

The code is running , but when I am producing messages, nothing is inserted in the HDFS.

It would be really helpful if someone can point what I am missing.

The code that I have tried is..

```
KafkaChannel channel = new KafkaChannel();

Map<String, String> channelParamters = new HashMap<String, String>();

channelParamters.put("brokerList", "localhost:9092");
channelParamters.put("zookeeperConnect","localhost:2181");
channelParamters.put("topic","integration");
channelParamters.put("groupId","channel");
channelParamters.put("batchSize", "15");
channelParamters.put("zookeeper.connect","localhost:2181");
channelParamters.put("clientId", "channel");
channelParamters.put("readSmallestOffset","true");
channelParamters.put("interceptors","i1");
channelParamters.put("interceptors.i1.type","host");
channelParamters.put("consumer.timeout.ms","1000");

channelParamters.put("parseAsFlumeEvent", "false");

channel.setName("KafkaSource");

Context channelContext = new Context(channelParamters);


final Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<String, String>();

/** Sink Properties start **/

HDFSEventSink eventSink = new HDFSEventSink();

eventSink.setName("HDFSEventSink-" + "kafkaEventSink");

String hdfsBasePath = "hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/flume/events";

properties.put("hdfs.type", "hdfs");
properties.put("hdfs.path", hdfsBasePath + "/%Y/%m/%d/%H");
properties.put("hdfs.rollInterval ", "0");
properties.put("hdfs.rollSize ", "2048");
properties.put("hdfs.rollCount ", "0");
properties.put("hdfs.fileType ", " DataStream");
properties.put("channel", channel.getName());
properties.put("hdfs.maxOpenFiles", String.valueOf(1));

properties.put("hdfs.filePrefix ", " kafka_host");
properties.put("hdfs.fileSuffix ", " .txt");
properties.put("hdfs.idleTimeout ", "60");

/** Sink Properties end **/

Context sinkContext = new Context(properties);

eventSink.configure(sinkContext);

eventSink.setChannel(channel);

Configurables.configure(channel, channelContext);

eventSink.start();

channel.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear what you're trying to achieve with your custom Java code.

A better approach would be to use Kafka Connect (part of Apache Kafka), and the open source [HDFS connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-hdfs/docs/index.html). It does exactly what you're doing here, is just configuration files to set up, handles schemas, scales, does automatic failover , etc etc.

Comment: Thank you for taking out time to answer my question.
We tried using Kafka Connect and we were facing some issues. The requirement was also to keep the module Java based.
The main requirement would be storing the data from kafka topic to HDFS layer for further use, so we were trying to use kafka channel to store to HDFS event sink ( in the above code ).

Comment: If you want to post a question with your Kafka Connect issues I'd be happy to help. Writing this code yourself is kinda trying to solve a solved problem, and doing so through a bespoke code base with associated maintenance and support considerations.

Comment: So should I create a new question about the error or I can mention a small snippet of error that we faced in Kafka connect ?

Comment: I would post it as a new question.